# Python for loop to save keys and values containing a certain value

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, jupyter-lab

Assuming I have a python list & dictionary structure like this:

```
[ {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'},
  {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'},
  {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'},
  {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/'}]
```

I am trying to find the most effective way to

(i) loop through only the keys which = `'href'` and only the `'href'` keys who's values contain '`'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/'` and identify the values (`'http...'`) that contain `'recipes/cuisine'`, `'recipes/season'` and `'recipes/ingredient'`
(ii) save each full url value into separate lists (depending on which of the `'recipe/...'` conditions they meet) and named appropriate.

**Expected result:**

```
cuisine = ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/']
season = ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/']
type = ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/']
ingredient = ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/']
```

Any keys and / or values do not meet the above criteria are skipped.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Part (i) of the requirements does not contain 'condiment' but the Expected Result does.  Is `/type/condiment/` included, or excluded from the filtering?

Comment: Hi smart - thanks for pointing this flaw in my question. I should have made this clearer, condiment is NOT included. I also should have mentioned that my structure also have keys and values that are not equal to the examples I have above. In this case, I'm looking to have those excluded.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one simple one hope you'll find it helpful

```
import re

trash = [ {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'},
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'},
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'},
          {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/'}]

for x in trash:
    for y in x.values():
        txt = ''
        for i in re.findall("recipes/.*", y):
            txt += i
            title = txt.split('/')[1]
            print({title: y})
```

output

```
{'cuisine': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'}
{'season': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'}
{'type': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'}
{'ingredient': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/'}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great contribution. Unfortunately when I run the code using the trash dict, it works great. However when I run using my structure, I get a 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. Presumably this is because my structure contains keys and values are are not iterable with your code. Is there anyway I could evolve this code, so that if the key is not equal to 'href', that key and value are skipped?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the urls follow the same format in the attached question. A better way is to create a dict of different recipes.

```
In [50]: from collections import defaultdict

In [51]: sep_data = defaultdict(list)

In [52]: lst = [ {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'},
    ...:   {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'},
    ...:   {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'},
    ...:   {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/'}]

In [59]: for i in lst: sep_data[i["href"].split("/")[-3]].append(i["href"])

In [60]: sep_data
Out[60]:
defaultdict(list,
            {'cuisine': ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'],
             'season': ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'],
             'type': ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'],
             'ingredient': ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/']})
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I didn't think this would be relevant, but clearly a mistake. The keys won't always be named "href"; those that aren't "href" I'd like to ignore. How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

So, roughly

```py
from itertools import groupby
import re

lst = [ {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/'},
  {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/'},
  {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/type/condiment/'},
  {'href': 'https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/'}]

def f(i):
    x = re.findall("https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/([^/ ]+)/(?:[^/ ]+/?)+", i["href"]) 
    return x and x[0] or None

r = filter(lambda i: i[0] in ('cuisine', 'season', 'ingredient'), groupby(lst, f))
for i in r:
    print(f"{i[0]} = {list(map(lambda j: j['href'], i[1]))}")

# result:
# cuisine = ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/cuisine/portuguese/']
# season = ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/season/seasonal_favorites_spring/']
# ingredient = ['https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/ingredient/adobado/']
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I get a TypeError:f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given' error.